# Error while compiling gdb

Tags: linux, python-2.7, compiler-errors, gdb

I get the following error when compiling GDB.

```
       ../readline/libreadline.a ../opcodes/libopcodes.a ../bfd/libbfd.a  ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a    -ldl -ltermcap -lz -lm    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython2.7 -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lexpat ../libiberty/libiberty.a  build-gnulib/import/libgnu.a 
python.o: In function `gdbpy_target_charset':
python.c:(.text+0x7b5): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
python.o: In function `gdbpy_target_wide_charset':
python.c:(.text+0x820): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
py-cmd.o: In function `cmdpy_function':
py-cmd.c:(.text+0x39b): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
py-cmd.o: In function `cmdpy_completer':
py-cmd.c:(.text+0x74c): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
py-cmd.c:(.text+0x7c0): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
py-frame.o:py-frame.c:(.text+0x29b): more undefined references to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode' follow
py-utils.o: In function `python_string_to_unicode':
py-utils.c:(.text+0xe1): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_FromEncodedObject'
py-utils.o: In function `unicode_to_encoded_string':
py-utils.c:(.text+0x13c): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString'
py-utils.o: In function `unicode_to_encoded_python_string':
py-utils.c:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_AsEncodedString'
py-utils.o: In function `target_string_to_unicode':
py-utils.c:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
py-value.o: In function `valpy_string':
py-value.c:(.text+0xb8b): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
py-value.o: In function `valpy_str':
py-value.c:(.text+0x141b): undefined reference to `PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [gdb] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory
```

What might be the reason for it?

Comment: Looks like some library or header file has an unexpected value here. Some symbol is defined during the compilation step, but then that symbol cannot be referenced at link time. You can gogole for that symbol name (`PyUnicodeUCS2_Decode`) and find out what library or module it is defined by. Then you can  go on to check for the versions and variants if you can find any incompatibilities between installed libraries and header files. This can happen if you have multiple versions of some component installed. Or some outdated files somehow leftover. Or if you make a "dirty install".

Comment: I found only PyUnicodeUCS4_Decode symbol in my python library

Comment: Perhaps you need to update Python.

Comment: I suggested to google for that symbol (sorry for the typo above...), not to look for it in your installed packages. Since obviously it does _not_ exist locally. Google easily revealed this: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/extending.html#when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2